# Game Menu Opening Randomly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

This has started happening since the 1.9+ releases. I'm not pressing any keys; I even did a test to see if it did it without me pressing any keys - it did it anyways. I counted and it has a delay of a minute and 15 seconds.

It doesn't have to do with breaking or placing blocks, whenever you do anything after the delay, even standing still doing nothing, you will still get the game menu. I have tried updating java and restarting. I don't have Google Chrome open or anything except the game and sometimes Firefox.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Game Menu?"

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. He probably means the menu that pops up when you press `[Esc]`.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. for more specific, the menu when you start your game.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. it's the esc that brings up the menu ingame

Answer (score 1):

Try getting new batteries in your keyboard.

This always happens to my mouse when its batteries are low; it glitches and clicks randomly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling your Minecraft launcher? This could fix the bug, if this doesn't work try moving the USB on your keyboard to another port.